# Update json encoded two dimensional array using SQL

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json, codeigniter

I have a database field `file_name` which stores the data as json encoded format which is a two dimensional array.

```
[{"211":"Rice.jpg"},{"212":"Cadbury_5_star_Chocolate.jpg"},{"213":"Strawberry.jpg"},{"214":"mung-dal-photo.jpg"}]
```

Is there any way to update the key value using where condition in SQL?

Comment: Update your question with expected result. And post your attempts too.

Comment: Yes its possible, you need to provide more information and with some example.

Comment: if this is encoded after your array structure was made, normally you just change the column names of what you want in directly your query, or if you're using active record, just change it there

Comment: MySQL doesn't have any tools to manipulate JSON out of the box. That's why you shouldn't store data like this, you should normalise the data into tables, rows and columns if you need SQL to work with it. Otherwise you'll have to do the manipulation in PHP.